# Subtraction Not Working

Tags: objective-c, operators

The below code doesn't work (It is in `touchesBegan`)

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

NSUInteger a = touchLocation.y;
NSUInteger b = touchLocation.x;
NSUInteger c = _player.center.y;
NSUInteger d = _player.center.x;

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) b);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) a);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) d);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) c);

int offSetY = a - c;
int offSetX = b - d;
float slope = (offSetY/offSetX);

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) offSetX);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) offSetY);
NSLog(@"%f", slope);
```

Well that's 75% true. When I tap in the top right hand quadrant of the screen the result every single variable is fine but `offSetX` which is off the charts (usually over 1800000000 more or less). Can anyone help me out? I don't see why this would go wrong.

Comment: why are you converting to `NSUInteger`? why not use `CGFloat`?

Comment: Show us the values that are being printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting to `NSUInteger` to just calculate slope? Use `CGFloat` instead.

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

CGPoint playerPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);

CGFloat a = touchLocation.y;
CGFloat b = touchLocation.x;
CGFloat c = playerPoint.y;
CGFloat d = playerPoint.x;

NSLog(@"%f", b);
NSLog(@"%f", a);
NSLog(@"%f", d);
NSLog(@"%f", c);

CGFloat offSetY = a - c;
CGFloat offSetX = b - d;
CGFloat slope = (offSetY/offSetX);

NSLog(@"%f", offSetX);
NSLog(@"%f", offSetY);
NSLog(@"%f", slope);
```